how to setup a shortcut key in outlook to "Mark all as read" a folder?
ATT. I need to set my own shortcut key to let a folder "Mark all as read". so that i could just press shortcut key to mark all mails as read.

Use the macro recorder?

thank you @stackoverflow to close my question with such none programming like reason, tbh all my programming questions could be answered by copilot/gpt, there is no more reason to ask them here.
I thought stackoverflow should still have “human touch” so that i still come back, but seems i am wrong. Thank all who negative my question and close it in this way.

Questions need to be about a specific programming issue. You've not shown any issue, only what you're goal is. There is no indication that you've tried anything yourself and your ChatGPT comment suggests your just prompting us for a solution without putting effort in yourself.
